# TM symbol rendering as &trade; in Kendo window title

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, unicode-string

I have a very basic Kendo window where I need to have the TM symbol included in the title. For some reason it is rendering as ™ and I haven't been able to find anything online pertaining to this specific situation.

Here is my code, the title I am having a problem with is at the bottom:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("SmartHomeTerminationModal")
.Actions(a => a.Minimize().Close())
.Animation(false)
.Content(
    @<text>
        <div class="container-fluid midco-k-window-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Install Date</th>
                                <th>Months in Contract</th>
                                <th>Months Remaining</th>
                                <th>Equipment Fee</th>
                                <th style="width: 20px;"></th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Model.InstallDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                                <td>@Model.MonthsInContract</td>
                                <td>@Model.MonthsRemaining</td>
                                <td>@Model.EquipmentFee.ToString("C")</td>
                                <td>=</td>
                                <td><strong>@Model.EquipmentFee.ToString("C")</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.ErrorMessage("We were unable to retrieve SmartHOME termination fee information.")
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </text>)
.Draggable()
.Title("SmartHOME&trade;")
.Visible(false)
.Width(800))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the TM symbol to the title string using the alt code. To do this hold Alt and type the code (0153 for TM) within the title string.

```
.Title("SmartHOME™")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by binding an event to the opening of the window like so:

```
.Events(eve => eve.Open("onOpen"))
```

then attaching a simple function to it

```
function onOpen(e) {

        var title = $("span.k-window-title"); 

        title.html('&trade; hello');
    }
```

this just targets the window title and then you apply whatever text you want in there so if you want an icon or something else there then you can apply it in here.